# Error when invoking arangoimp in the shell

Tags: arangodb, arangoimport

When I try to invoke arangoimp with the following:

`Applications/ArangoDB3-CLI.app/Contents/Resources/arangoimp`  in my terminal I get the following error:

`2018-03-12T11:26:43Z [49366] ERROR Could not connect to endpoint 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', database: '_system', username: 'root'
2018-03-12T11:26:43Z [49366] FATAL got error from server: HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)'`

I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 401 means the specified username and/or password are incorrect for the selected database.

It seems you are using database `_system` with user root. If you have set a password, you either need to specify it via the option `--server.password "your-password-goes-here"` or omit it and type it when the ArangoShell prompts.
If the password is incorrect, or the user does not exist, then the arangod server will respond with HTTP 401.

Comment: now I am one step further: `Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', version 3.3.4, database: '_system', username: 'root'
----------------------------------------
database:               _system
collection:             
create:                 no
source filename:        
file type:              json
threads:                2
connect timeout:        5
request timeout:        1200
----------------------------------------
2018-03-12T12:35:58Z [49727] FATAL Collection name is missing.`

Comment: Hi @CodeHip, it would be helpful if you not only pasted the output you got, but also the complete command you executed.

Comment: I just grab the arangoimp exec from where it is located, I updated above.

Comment: @CodeHip See the documentation for examples how to use `arangoimp`: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Administration/Arangoimp.html or run it with the option `--help` to get a list of parameters.